# starting a batch file that is inside of an folder at from the desktop

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to launch a batch file that is inside another folder from a batch file that is on my desktop. 
Pretty hard to explain but what I am trying to do is get 3 .bat files, all from different folders to start-up in multiple bat files and not one, I tried to use `start` in the bat file but it didn't work as it ran the code from another batch at the desktop. but I really just need all of the three batch files to launch from the destination, as if I launched them manually.

this is what it tells me when I use `start` in a batch file to the destination:

```
C:\Users\Serv2\Desktop>java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
Error: Unable to access jarfile server.jar
```

and this is in my batch file:

```
call start C:\Users\Serv2\Documents\Server\run.bat
```

Comment: That error is coming from the secondary batch file you are running, but you have failed to show us the code for that batch file.

Comment: Use a fully qualified path to `server.jar` (absolute or relative to the script).

Comment: `Call` each batch file, with its absolute or relative path. Within each of those batch files, set the working directory at the beginning, use the absolute or relative path to every file and use `GoTo :EOF` instead of `Exit`, _(or alternatively include its `/B` option)_.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this is what you are looking for but i found this on super user

call "your folder"\"name of your .bat file"

orginal source:
https://superuser.com/questions/1412747/how-to-run-a-bat-from-batch-in-another-folder

Comment: although it works, it's very bad practice. Always quote the complete path, never single elements: `call "your folder\name of your .bat file"`